# Getting Hourly statistics using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, report

We have a table, name *'employeeReg'* with fields

```
employeeNo | employeeName | Registered_on
```

Here *Registered_on* is a timestamp.

We require an hourly pattern of registrations, over a period of days. eg.

> 01 Jan 08 : 12 - 01 PM : 1592 registrations
>
> 01 Jan 08 : 01 - 02 PM : 1020 registrations

Can someone please suggest a query for this.

---

We are using Oracle 10gR2 as our DB server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is closely related to, but slightly different from, this question about [How to get the latest record for each day when there are multiple entries per day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384142/how-to-get-latest-record-for-each-day-when-there-are-multiple-entries-per-day).  (*One point in common with many, many SQL questions - the table name was not given originally!*)

The basic technique will be to find a function that will format the varied Registered_on values such that all the entries in a particular hour are grouped together.  This presumably can be done with `TO_CHAR()` since we're dealing with Oracle (MySQL does not support this).

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(Registered_on, "YYYY-MM-DD HH24") AS TimeSlot,
       COUNT(*) AS Registrations
    FROM EmployeeReg
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY 1;
```

You might be able to replace the '1' entries by TimeSlot, or by the `TO_CHAR()` expression; however, for reasons of backwards compatibility, it is likely that this will work as written (but I cannot verify that for you on Oracle - an equivalent works OK on IBM Informix Dynamic Server using `EXTEND(Registered_on, YEAR TO HOUR)` in place of `TO_CHAR()`).

If you then decide you want zeroes to appear for hours when there are no entries, then you will need to create a list of all the hours you do want reported, and you will need to do a LEFT OUTER JOIN of that list with the result from this query.  The hard part is generating the correct list - different DBMS have different ways of doing it.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, sorry for missing that. Have given the table name now.

Comment: NP: It was a wry observation based on answering a fair number of SQL questions.  I've updated the answer appropriately - I've left the 'One point in common' sentence in place, but italicized it, and added 'originally'.

Answer (score 2):

**Achieved what I wanted, with** :)

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(a.registered_on, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24') AS TimeSlot,
       COUNT(*) AS Registrations
    FROM EmployeeReg a
    Group By TO_CHAR(a.registered_on, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24');
```